# Vanilla Javascript: How to make cells multiple different colours on a grid with user colour input

Tags: javascript, colors, color-picker

***What I'm building***

Hi guys! I'm building a Pixel Art Maker.

It's basically a grid, and each cell on the grid changes colour when you click on it.

It's an application that *should* allow for different colours on the same canvas.

***Problem:***

How do I allow for multiple different colours on the same grid, with user-selected color input?

I know how to make it all black, for example (it's hardcoded at the moment), but if I wanted to add more colours, how do I do that?

***JS Fiddle Demo***

https://jsfiddle.net/JayS5/foznjb2m/

***JS Code***

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas')

const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.target.style.background = 'black';
});

canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});

// Store the value of columns
const column = document.getElementById('column');

// Store the value of rows
const row = document.getElementById('row');

// Access forms
const submitForm = document.querySelector('#submitForm');

submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  // Prevents the submit button from refreshing the page by default
  tbody.innerHTML = "";

  // Color picker

  const colorPicker = document.createElement('div');
  colorPicker.setAttribute("id", "ActiveColor")

  colorPicker.innerHTML = '<input type="color" id="head" name="color" value="#e66465"/>';

  document.body.appendChild(colorPicker);

  // Generate grid

  for (r = 0; r < row.value; r++) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    for (c = 0; c < column.value; c++) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
    } 
    canvas.appendChild(tbody);  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be better to put the color picker input element into the HTML at the beginning, so that you can select it on the top level without reassignment. When the form is submitted, make it visible. Then, on click, just access that element's `value` and assign it to the `background` property:

```
const colorInput = document.querySelector('input[type="color"]');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.background = colorInput.value;
});
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas')
const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
const colorInput = document.querySelector('input[type="color"]');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.background = colorInput.value;
});

canvas.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});


const column = document.getElementById('column');
const row = document.getElementById('row');
const submitForm = document.querySelector('#submitForm');

submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the submit button from refreshing the page by default
  colorInput.style.display = 'inline';
  tbody.innerHTML = "";
  // Generate grid

  for (r = 0; r < row.value; r++) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    for (c = 0; c < column.value; c++) {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    canvas.appendChild(tbody);
  }
});
```

```css
/**
 * index.scss
 * - Add any styles you want here!
 */

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

table,
thead,
tbody,
tfoot,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

td {
  width: 30px;
}

tr {
  height: 30px;
}
input[type="color"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Grid Size</legend>

  <form id='submitForm'>

    <label for="height">Columns:</label>
    <input type="number" id="column" placeholder="Key in an integer" step="1" />

    <label for="width">Rows:</label>
    <input type="number" id="row" placeholder="Min: 1, max: 100" min="1" max="100" />

    <div>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br>

<br>

<div>
  <table id="pixelCanvas">
    <!--  Dynamic pixel canvas  -->
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="color" value="#e66465" />
</div>
```

Comment: I just have a couple of questions because I don't quite understand how the solution works. What do these lines mean? let colorPickerInput; and colorInput.style.display = 'inline'; .

I've also been looking for the documentation for this specific line, but I don't know what it's called:  ('input[type="color"]')

Comment: The `let colorPickerInput` was from a variable from a test that I later didn't use, I forgot to delete it. The `'input[type="color"]'` is called a *selector string*. You can read about selectors [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). That string means select the `input` element which has an attribute `type` whose value is `color`. (Of course, feel free to use IDs instead, if you want)

Comment: I really appreciate the clarification! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add event onchange and write color to global varible color

```
  colorPicker.onchange = function (e) {
    color = e.target.value
  }
```

[Full code](https://jsfiddle.net/rnm7k92f/1/)